# Weierstrass theorem (extreme value theorem) for $f(x) = x^2-\sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. $$f(x) = x^2-\sin(x)$$
>
> Show using Weierstrass theorem that the function achieves a minimum value on it's domain.

I approached this the following way. (I'm not sure if im heading to the right direction):

Since $$\lim_{x\to± \infty} f(x) = \infty$$ and $$f(1) =1-\sin(1) $$ we can take the interval $[-a, a]$ and when $|f(x)| > 1-\sin(1)$, we know by the Weierstrass theorem that on the interval $[-a, a]$ $f$ achieves it's minimum value.

Comment: "...the interval $\;[-a,a]\;$ ..." . **What** interval?

Comment: Can’t the choice of $[-a, a]$ be arbitary as long as it holds that outside it $ |f(x)| > 1-\sin(1)$?

Comment: Indeed it can, yet you still must make clearer your argument. So by W. Theorem $\;f\;$ obtains its minimal value in that closed interval...how does that makes sure that minimum is a global one? You almost have it, in fact...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. Since $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=+\infty$, there exists an $A>0$ such that when $|x|>A$, we have $f(x)>1$. In the interval $[-A,A]$ the function is continuous, so by the extreme value theorem there is an $m\in[-A,A]$ such that $f(m)\leq f(x)$ for $|x|\leq A$. Since $0\in[-A,A]$, $f(m)\leq f(0)=0<1$. But we have $f(x)>1$ for $|x|>A$. Hence, $f(m)\leq f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

We can also do this with $f(1)=1-\sin(1)$. There exists an $A>1$ such that when $|x|>A$, we have $f(x)>1-\sin(1)$. Now consider the interval $[-A,A]$ which contains $1$, and we can finish the proof in the same way. Note that $A>1$ is needed to ensure $1$ is in the interval.

Comment: How did you choose the $1$ for $f(x) > 1$?

Comment: @Daniel It follows from the definition of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. For any $M$, there is an $A$ such that when $x>A$, we have $f(x)>M$. So we can choose $M=1$.

Comment: That I understand, but how can we determine appropriate value for $M$?

Comment: You simply have to find one that works, and almost any choice will work here. For instance, $M=1-\sin(1)$ can also do. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.